Having problem with canonicalization while doing kerberos authentication in websphere
hostname cannonicalization resolves ip instead of hostname for IBM websphere server.
I can have ticket manually using kinit within the server with my keytab file but the application gives error while doing kerberos authentication.
The actual error in SystemErr.log file:
SystemErr     R com.ibm.security.krb5.KrbException, status code: 7
    message: :kafka/10.230.xxx.xxx@FW.OGUZHAN.COM.TR

My jaas.conf file:
KafkaClient {
   com.ibm.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
   credsType=both
   useKeytab="/path/to/keytab/oguzhan.keytab"
   principal="oguzhan@FW.OGUZHAN.COM.TR";
};

My kerberos logs:
 [KRB_DBG_CFG] Config:arkSecurityAccessTokenScheduler-1:  kafka-producer-network-thread | rp_uxpmobil_cs readKrb5Properties: defaultRealm = null
     [KRB_DBG_CFG] Config:arkSecurityAccessTokenScheduler-1:  kafka-producer-network-thread | rp_uxpmobil_cs readKrb5Properties: defaultKDC   = null
     [KRB_DBG_CFG] Config:arkSecurityAccessTokenScheduler-1:  kafka-producer-network-thread | rp_uxpmobil_cs getKDCList: realm = FW.oguzhan.COM.TR
     [KRB_DBG_CFG] Config:arkSecurityAccessTokenScheduler-1:  kafka-producer-network-thread | rp_uxpmobil_cs getKDCList: kdcs  = ogznet12.fw.oguzhan.com.tr:88 com.tr:88 ogznet4.fw.oguzhan.com.tr:88 ogznet6.fw.oguzhan.com.tr:88 ogznet8.fw.oguzhan.com.tr:88 ogznet5.fw.oguzhan.com.tr:88
     [KRB_DBG_KDC] KdcComm:arkSecurityAccessTokenScheduler-1:  kafka-producer-network-thread | rp_uxpmobil_cs >>> KdcComm send: kdc=ogznet12.fw.oguzhan.com.tr TCP:88, 
     [KRB_DBG_KDC] KdcComm:arkSecurityAccessTokenScheduler-1:  kafka-producer-network-thread | rp_uxpmobil_cs >>> KdcCommunication: kdc=ogznet12.fw.oguzhan.com.tr TCP:88, 
     [KRB_DBG_KDC] KdcComm:arkSecurityAccessTokenScheduler-1:  kafka-producer-network-thread | rp_uxpmobil_cs >>> KdcComm send: #bytes read=100
     [KRB_DBG_KDC] KdcComm:arkSecurityAccessTokenScheduler-1:  kafka-producer-network-thread | rp_uxpmobil_cs >>> KdcAccessibility: remove ogznet12.fw.oguzhan.com.tr:88
     [KRB_DBG_CFG] KDCRep:kafka-producer-network-thread | rp_uxpmobil_cs:   >>> KDCRep: init() encoding tag is 126 req type is 13
     [KRB_DBG_KDC] KRBError:kafka-producer-network-thread | rp_uxpmobil_cs:   >>>KRBError:
     [KRB_DBG_KDC] KRBError:kafka-producer-network-thread | rp_uxpmobil_cs:      sTime is Fri Apr 05 09:26:12 TRT 2024 1712298372000
     [KRB_DBG_KDC] KRBError:kafka-producer-network-thread | rp_uxpmobil_cs:      suSec is 136042
     **[KRB_DBG_KDC] KRBError:kafka-producer-network-thread | rp_uxpmobil_cs:        error code is 7
     [KRB_DBG_KDC] KRBError:kafka-producer-network-thread | rp_uxpmobil_cs:      error Message is Server not found in Kerberos database**
     [KRB_DBG_KDC] KRBError:kafka-producer-network-thread | rp_uxpmobil_cs:      sname is kafka/10.230.xxx.x@FW.oguzhan.COM.TR
     [KRB_DBG_KDC] KRBError:kafka-producer-network-thread | rp_uxpmobil_cs:      msgType is 30
     [JGSS_DBG_CRED]  kafka-producer-network-thread | rp_uxpmobil_cs MN not found; creating one
     [JGSS_DBG_PROV]  kafka-producer-network-thread | rp_uxpmobil_cs Provider Entry: provider: IBMJGSSProvider, mechanism: 1.3.6.1.5.5.2 get Factory for mech: 
     [JGSS_DBG_PROV]  kafka-producer-network-thread | rp_uxpmobil_cs Provider Entry: provider: IBMJGSSProvider, mechanism: 1.2.840.113554.1.2.2 get Factory for mech: 
     [JGSS_DBG_PROV]  kafka-producer-network-thread | rp_uxpmobil_cs getFactory: index = 1 found factory caller = GSSCaller{UNKNOWN}
     **[JGSS_DBG_CRED]  kafka-producer-network-thread | rp_uxpmobil_cs Before Cannonicalizing hostbased service name kafka@gbccccc23.fw.oguzhan.com.tr
     [KRB_DBG_CFG] Config:arkSecurityAccessTokenScheduler-1:  kafka-producer-network-thread | rp_uxpmobil_cs get: section     = libdefaults
     [KRB_DBG_CFG] Config:arkSecurityAccessTokenScheduler-1:  kafka-producer-network-thread | rp_uxpmobil_cs get: name        = dns_lookup_realm
     [KRB_DBG_CFG] Config:arkSecurityAccessTokenScheduler-1:  kafka-producer-network-thread | rp_uxpmobil_cs get: result      = true
     [JGSS_DBG_CRED]  kafka-producer-network-thread | rp_uxpmobil_cs FQDN=10.230.xxx.xx
     [JGSS_DBG_CRED]  kafka-producer-network-thread | rp_uxpmobil_cs Cannonicalizing hostbased service name kafka@10.230.xxx.xx
     [JGSS_DBG_CRED]  kafka-producer-network-thread | rp_uxpmobil_cs Hostname 10.230.xxx.xx
     [KRB_DBG_CFG] Config:arkSecurityAccessTokenScheduler-1:  kafka-producer-network-thread | rp_uxpmobil_cs readKrb5Properties: defaultRealm = null
     [KRB_DBG_CFG] Config:arkSecurityAccessTokenScheduler-1:  kafka-producer-network-thread | rp_uxpmobil_cs readKrb5Properties: defaultKDC   = null
     [KRB_DBG_CFG] Config:arkSecurityAccessTokenScheduler-1:  kafka-producer-network-thread | rp_uxpmobil_cs get: section     = libdefaults
     [KRB_DBG_CFG] Config:arkSecurityAccessTokenScheduler-1:  kafka-producer-network-thread | rp_uxpmobil_cs get: name        = default_realm
     [KRB_DBG_CFG] Config:arkSecurityAccessTokenScheduler-1:  kafka-producer-network-thread | rp_uxpmobil_cs get: result      = FW.oguzhan.COM.TR
     [KRB_DBG_CFG] Config:arkSecurityAccessTokenScheduler-1:  kafka-producer-network-thread | rp_uxpmobil_cs getDefaultRealm: realm = FW.oguzhan.COM.TR
     [KRB_DBG_CFG] Config:arkSecurityAccessTokenScheduler-1:  kafka-producer-network-thread | rp_uxpmobil_cs readKrb5Properties: defaultRealm = null
     [KRB_DBG_CFG] Config:arkSecurityAccessTokenScheduler-1:  kafka-producer-network-thread | rp_uxpmobil_cs readKrb5Properties: defaultKDC   = null
     [KRB_DBG_CFG] Config:arkSecurityAccessTokenScheduler-1:  kafka-producer-network-thread | rp_uxpmobil_cs get: section     = libdefaults
     [KRB_DBG_CFG] Config:arkSecurityAccessTokenScheduler-1:  kafka-producer-network-thread | rp_uxpmobil_cs get: name        = default_realm
     [KRB_DBG_CFG] Config:arkSecurityAccessTokenScheduler-1:  kafka-producer-network-thread | rp_uxpmobil_cs get: result      = FW.oguzhan.COM.TR
     [KRB_DBG_CFG] Config:arkSecurityAccessTokenScheduler-1:  kafka-producer-network-thread | rp_uxpmobil_cs getDefaultRealm: realm = FW.oguzhan.COM.TR
     [JGSS_DBG_CRED]  kafka-producer-network-thread | rp_uxpmobil_cs Name cannonicalization complete, resulting name string=kafka/10.230.xxx.xx@FW.oguzhan.COM.TR**

i have krb5.conf file too but i can't share it due to classified information inside it. (whic works for other kafka integrations across the company)
and related vm arguments that app use:
-Djava.security.auth.login.config= path.to.jaas.conf

-Djava.security.krb5.conf= path.to.krb5.conf

im suspecting that cannonicalization resolves ip value instead of gbccccc23 and it forces kerberos to use ip instead of FQDN so im having status code: 7 error.
any ideas why cannonicalization returns ip?

Just a thought - "The canonicalization technique uses the DNS. The Kerberos libraries take the hostname given by the user, perform a DNS lookup to get the host’s IP address, and perform a reverse lookup on the IP address to get the host’s primary DNS fully-qualified domain name." - are you sure that there is a (A) record in the DNS for the 10.230.xxx.x IP address? Also double check what actually is in your keytab file...

i acquired ticket manually by using kinit with my keytab and im pretty sure it has no problem. But not really sure about the DNS i'm not permitted to check it in the server.

Can you clarify whether this webapp receives Kerberos auth from clients, or whether it uses Kerberos auth to connect to some other service?

It doesn't receive it from the client. it uses kerberos authentication to do kafka publishing via the mutliple kafka brokers which is gbccccc23 for this logs case. All of the brokers logged as the same error log
